# Trouble showing Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm working with Boostrap Modal, and I have a trouble, the model isn't displayed. I am working with laravel, so I will post the code generated. I have hours trying to make it works, so I will really appreciate your help. this is the HTML code:

http://pastebin.com/UyB8CssU

the code is:

the link that should shows me the modal:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DetalleSol1">
```

The modal:

```
<!--Modal for Solicitud-->
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="DetalleSol1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mylabelmodal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close1"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="mylabelmodal1">Detalles de Solicitud</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                   <label>Estudiante: </label> Tito Schulist MD Ryan<br>
                   <label>Tipo: </label>Reintegro<br>
                   <label>Estado:</label>Pendiente<br>
                   <label>Fecha: </label> 2015-12-07 23:02:06<br>
                   <Details><summary><label>Detalle: </label></summary><p>ejemplo de <b>reintegro</b> </p></Details><br>
                    <a id="button1" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " href="http://localhost/passport/passport/public/secretaria/solicitudes/pdf/doc_1449529325.pdf" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download" style="margin-right: 3px;"></i><label>Descargar adjunto</label></a>                                                    
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline center-block" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you just post the modal `div` and its invoking button or anchor? Makes it easy to look at

Comment: @VishalSh edited man! I posted all the code because I have there various modals, I don't know if there's something wrapping other

Comment: I could get this working. I just added jquery CDN followed by bootstrap CSS and JS. Also, I'd suggest to use only one modal and just replace the content in the same, using jQuery or javascript.

Comment: @VishalSh I added this, but nothing. The screen get stoped as if the modal will show but nothing.thanks

Comment: There is any reason why you have two times a link to the bootstrap.css frame work in your HTML? If you use two different version of them you will get troubles.

Comment: @Franco no man! this is because are nested views, and some of the add it

Comment: try removing every other modal, have only one modal in your page and see if its working with only 1. Can you see your browser console logs as well? What is shown there?

Comment: You can have nested views in Laravel this in not a problem, what I see in your generated HTML are the following two files:<link href="http://localhost/passport/passport/public/adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

Comment: @VishalSh but actually, I have another view with various modals and it works fine.but for some reason not in this one

Comment: I am braking my head with this, I would like you to post your code here. Looking in the pastebin is difficult to do. I can be wrong but I have noticed that you have an extra closing </div> at the end of the modal.